# Asyncio gather difference

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

From my understanding, both the code blocks are doing the same thing. Why there is a difference in execution time?

```py
import asyncio
import time
...

# Block 1:
start_time = time.time()
tasks = [
    get_from_knowledge_v2(...),
    get_from_knowledge_v2(...),
    get_from_knowledge_v2(...),
]
data_list = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
print("TIME TAKEN::", time.time() - start_time)

# Block 2:
start_time = time.time()
data1 = await get_from_knowledge_v2(...)
data2 = await get_from_knowledge_v2(...)
data3 = await get_from_knowledge_v2(...)
print("WITHOUT ASYNCIO GATHER TIME TAKEN::", time.time() - start_time)
```

Result:

```
TIME TAKEN:: 0.6016566753387451
WITHOUT ASYNCIO GATHER TIME TAKEN:: 1.7620849609375
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) function runs the awaitables you pass to it concurrently. That means, if I/O is happening in at least one of them that allows for useful context switches by the event loop. That in turn leads to a certain degree of parallelism.

In this case I assume that `get_from_knowledge_v2` does some HTTP request in a way that supports asynchronous execution.

In the second code block you have **no concurrency** between the three `get_from_knowledge_v2` calls. Instead you just execute them **sequentially** (with respect to each other). In other words, while you are `await`ing the first one of them, the second one will not start. Their context is **blocked**.

**Note:** This does not mean that *outside* of that code block no concurrency is happening/possible. If this sequential code block is inside an `async` function (i.e. coroutine), you can execute that concurrently with some other coroutine. It is just that *inside* that code block, those `get_from_knowledge_v2` coroutines are executed sequentially.

The time you measured confirms this rather nicely since you have **three** coroutines and `gather` allows them to be executed almost in parallel, while the other code block executes them sequentially, thus leading to an almost **three times** longer execution time.

### PS

Maybe a minimal concrete example will help illustrate what I mean:

```py
from asyncio import gather, run, sleep
from time import time


async def sleep_and_print(seconds: float) -> None:
    await sleep(seconds)
    print("slept", seconds, "seconds")


async def concurrent_sleeps() -> None:
    await gather(
        sleep_and_print(3),
        sleep_and_print(2),
        sleep_and_print(1),
    )


async def sequential_sleeps() -> None:
    await sleep_and_print(3)
    await sleep_and_print(2)
    await sleep_and_print(1)


async def something_else() -> None:
    print("Doing something else that takes 4 seconds...")
    await sleep(4)
    print("Done with something else!")


async def main() -> None:
    start = time()
    await concurrent_sleeps()
    print("concurrent_sleeps took", round(time() - start, 1), "seconds\n")

    start = time()
    await sequential_sleeps()
    print("sequential_sleeps took", round(time() - start, 1), "seconds\n")

    start = time()
    await gather(
        sequential_sleeps(),
        something_else(),
    )
    print("sequential_sleeps & something_else together took", round(time() - start, 1), "seconds")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())
```

Running that script gives the following output:

```
slept 1 seconds
slept 2 seconds
slept 3 seconds
concurrent_sleeps took 3.0 seconds

slept 3 seconds
slept 2 seconds
slept 1 seconds
sequential_sleeps took 6.0 seconds

Doing something else that takes 4 seconds...
slept 3 seconds
Done with something else!
slept 2 seconds
slept 1 seconds
sequential_sleeps & something_else together took 6.0 seconds
```

This illustrates that the sleeping was done almost in parallel inside `concurrent_sleeps`, with the 1 second sleep finishing first, then the 2 second sleep, then the 3 second sleep.

It shows that the sleeping is done sequentially inside `sequential_sleeps` and in the call order, meaning it first slept 3 seconds, then it slept 2 seconds, then 1 second.

And finally, executing `sequential_sleeps` concurrently with `something_else` shows that they are executed almost in parallel, with the 3-second-sleep finishing first (after 3 seconds), then one second later `something_else` finished, then another second later the 2-second-sleep, then after another second the 1-second-sleep. Together they still took approximately 6 seconds.

That last part is what I meant, when I said you an still execute another coroutine concurrently with the sequential block of code. In itself, the code block will still always remain sequential.

I hope this is clearer now.

### PPS

Just to throw another option into the mix, you can also achieve concurrency by using `Task`s. Calling [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) will **immediately** schedule the coroutine for execution on the event loop. The task it creates should be awaited at some point, but the underlying coroutine will start running almost immediately after calling `create_task`. You can add this to the example script above:

```py
from asyncio import create_task
...
async def task_sleeps() -> None:
    t3 = create_task(sleep_and_print(3))
    t2 = create_task(sleep_and_print(2))
    t1 = create_task(sleep_and_print(1))
    await t3
    await t2
    await t1

async def main() -> None:
    ...
    start = time()
    await task_sleeps()
    print("task_sleeps took", round(time() - start, 1), "seconds\n")
```

And you'll see the following again:

```
...
slept 1 seconds
slept 2 seconds
slept 3 seconds
task_sleeps took 3.0 seconds
```

Tasks are a nice option to decouple the execution of some coroutine from its surrounding context to an extent, but you need to keep track of them in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I tried the second block of sequential calling using await inside another async function to see if that works concurrently but it still works the same way(sequentially). And yes get_from_knowledge function has an async HTTP request inside it. Still not able to understand why this behavior.

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava You misunderstood me. The second block (i.e. the three `get_from_knowledge_v2` calls) will **always** be executed sequentially. I meant, if you put that in an `async` function `f`, you can execute `f` concurrently with some other `async` function. But the code _inside_ `f` will always be executed sequentially.

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava I added a very simple example script to my answer that should make it clearer what I meant. Is my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted.